# A resource of exercises about induction and combinatorics

Tags: soft-question, induction, online-resources

I'm looking for a book, webpage or similar resource with a lot of exercises about induction and combinatorics at basic level.

Comment: I seem to recall a slim volume translated from Russian consisting of a large number of exercises on mathematical induction.  I don't remember what it was called.  Does anyone?

Answer (score 3):

***A path to combinatorics for undergraduates***, by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng.

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Trotter is kind enough to provide freely his [textbook](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~trotter/math-3012-Fa11/toppage.htm) at his website. It is focused towards early combinatorics and the third chapter is devoted towards induction. I think it's a great read.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the counting problems in alcumus:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Alcumus/Introduction.php

Answer (score 1):

There are the assignments of the Art of Counting course in MIT: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s66-the-art-of-counting-spring-2003/assignments/
They are pretty good